# Matlab: How to re-order (re-organize) a matrix

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix

I have a random column matrix:

```
r = rand(1,300)';
```

I want to re-order it so that instead of having elements in the order of 1,2,3,...,300
I will have elements 1,11,21,31,...,291,2,12,22,32,...,292,3,13,33,...293,...,300.

In other words, I want to take every 10th value, beginning with 1 and put them in that order, then do the same for 2 with every 10th value. I know one way to do this is:

```
n = 10;
r = [r(1:n:numel(r)); r(2:n:numel(r)); r(3:n:numel(r));...;r(10:n:numel(r))];  % Skipped 4-9 in this example
```

But obviously, this is very cumbersome to do more than a couple of times. Is there something more efficient?

A loop should be easy, but I am not doing it correctly, it seems (I can see why this might not work, but I can't correct it).

(Here is what I tried:)

```
n = 10;
for i = 1:10
a = [r(i:n:numel(r))];
end
```

Any suggestions or help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: convert to strings and use `sortrows`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
r = reshape(reshape(r, 10, 30)', 300, 1)
```

**EDIT:**

As pointed out by @LuisMendo on the comments, it's safer to use `.'` than `'` to transpose the matrix, because if the matrix is complex, that could introduce a complex conjugation. Then, it would be safer to do it like this:

```
r = reshape(reshape(r, 10, 30).', 300, 1)
```

Comment: You can use the default sizing option with `[]` - `r = reshape(reshape(r, 10, [])', [],1)`

Comment: +1 but my usual quibble: if `r` is complex you are inadvertently introducing a complex conjugation with `'`. Use `.'` instead

Comment: @LuisMendo: I didn't know that! I will edit my answer, so others won't make the same 'mistake'. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
intv = 10; %%// Interval after which you intend to get the values consecutively
out = r(reshape(reshape(1:numel(r),intv,[])',1,[]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could reshape it into `30x10` matrix, transpose, and take the flat index:

```
A = 1:300;
A = reshape(A,30,10);
A = A';
A = A(:);
```

Answer (score 1):

Some of the other solutions posted are more efficient, but your idea was a good one.  It requires a simple fix to work:

```
N = numel(r);
M = N/10;
a=[];
for ii = 1:M
        a= [a r(ii:10:N)];
end
```

Hope this helps